# Change route based on authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to change the route basing on authentication in MVC?

Home page and login page need to have the same Url.

In my case, The home page url is `site.com`. This is `Home Controller`, `Index Action`. 
The login url is `site.com\Account\Login`. This is `Account Controller`, `Login Action`.

I want to display login when a non authenticated user opens the site. But the Url needs to be `site.com` not `site.com\Account\Login`.

When he logs in, then the user will be redirected to `Home Controller`, `Index Action` and now also I need the same url.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the `Home` controller attribute `[Authorise]`, and then when accessing  main page site.com you are redirected to `site.com\Account\Login`

Comment: That is not what I asked for. I need the same url for both login and home based on authentication